# Function to search a mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a function to search through my database with particular criteria.

```
function searchOrders($keywords, $criteriaId, $dateEntered, $statusID)
```

That is the function I intend to use, I am wanting to build a query to search for each of those variables but also them combined. I am wondering what is the best way to do this?

e.g. They don't enter a keyword but the do enter a criteriaId or they enter both of them but leave out the date and states.

Any ideas would be appreciated as I've never had to build a search feature yet.

Comment: use PDO and create the database-statement with parameters and this assign these parameters your variable-values.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What does PDO stand for?

Comment: Here is the database design...not all of it, but what's relevant and also what the search looks like. http://i.imgur.com/167kP8A.jpg

Comment: Does PHP (or really, PDO) support a "Criteria Builder" API? Such exist on many ORM/DALs - at least in Java/.NET. Otherwise, it has to be specialized query generation if "and" and "or" logic must be dynamic and intermixed.

Comment: Just to mention, I got the answer first about a estructured function and @theghostofc edit your answer and put something similar to what I have after I had published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Just get your request variables from the querystring. If they're not there, set them to "" or NULL....

```
$keywords = $_GET["keywords"];
$criteriaId = $_GET["criteriaId"];
$dateEntered = $_GET["dateEntered"];
$statusID = $_GET["statusID"];
```

... and call the function:

```
$orders = searchOrders($keywords, $criteriaId, $dateEntered, $statusID);
```

In the searchOrders function, you may check if value for any parameter is "" (blank) or NULL and create your SQL query accordingly.

### Edit:

The trick here is to play with **where** and **and** keywords. (*Assuming you need only a where / and condition query and include a parameter if its value is not blank or NULL*)

```
public function searchOrders($keywords, $criteriaId, $dateEntered, $statusID)
{   
    $query = "select * from orders";
    $condition = " where ";

    if (!is_null($keywords)) {
        $query .= $condition . "keywords like '$keywords'";
        $condition = " and ";
    }

    if (!is_null($criteriaId)) {
        $query .= $condition . "criteriaId = $criteriaId";
        $condition = " and ";
    }

    if (!is_null($dateEntered)) {
        $query .= $condition . "dateEntered <= #$dateEntered#";
        $condition = " and ";
    }

    if (!is_null($statusID)) {
        $query .= $condition . "statusID = $statusID";
    }

    return mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: I know how to get the data, I just don't quite know how to build the query

Comment: You might like to provide more information about the table structure or resultant query with all valid parameters. Eg. Given all 4 valid parameters, would your query look like select * from orders where keywords like '$keywords' and criteriaId = $criteriaId and dateEntered <= #$dateEntered# and statudID = $statusID ... or something similar?

Comment: Table structure is in a comment up in the question. What if one of them is null and not entered, wouldn't it be searching for criteriaID 0 then?

Comment: I have edited my answer for NULL values. If this applies, you may modify the condition to include "" (blank) also

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun, see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql-connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli); [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks @vascowhite, the code was only for reference. It is advised to use PDO or any other ORM framework, at least for new code.

Comment: @theghostofc sorry, but I don't see that warning in your answer, you don't mention the dangers of using unsanitised user input either, which is what your code is doing.

Comment: @vascowhite, my intention was to give the asker a starting point, not a copy-paste solution. Still, thanks for sharing your concern. I'll keep your points in mind while answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

For example with simple mysql, you build some like this:

**call a function to get some data**

```
$data = selectSome("ID_User = '". $iduser ."' AND Situation != 0", 'table_example', 'Id_User, Name, Description, null, 'ID_User DESC', null);

/*Process $data */
```

**Function**

```
public function selectSome($SQL, $table = null, $fields = "*", $group = null, $order = null, $limit = null)
{       
    if (!is_null($group)) {
        $SQL .= " GROUP BY ". $group;
    }

    if (is_null($order)) { 
        $SQL .= "";     
    } elseif ($order === "DESC") {
        $SQL .= " ORDER BY $this->primaryKey DESC";
    } elseif (!is_null($order)) {  
        $SQL .= " ORDER BY ". $order;
    } elseif ($order === "") { 
        $SQL .= " ORDER BY $this->primaryKey";
    }

    if ($limit) {
        $SQL .= " LIMIT ". $limit;
    }

    $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $SQL";

    return mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);
}
```

It is a basic example of which can change some values ​​and get your desired function and change MYSQL to PDO or MYSQLI.

Comment: Thanks for your help this gave me some good ideas along with theghostofc's answer. Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this i dont know much about it but here's where i found it

> SELECT name, price, warranty_available, exclusive_offer
>   FROM Products
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT name, price, guarantee_available, exclusive_offer
>   FROM Services

[Union Query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010341541.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

try something like mine:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from colleges where Campus_Name like '%$term%' or Campus_Address like '%$term%' or 
    Campus_State like '%$term%' or Campus_City like '%$term%' or Campus_Zip like '%$term%' ");
```

Comment: The problem I see there is it's using or, I want it to be able to check for multiple fields. e.g. if keywords is entered and a criteriaID is entered it matches both conditions not just one of them.

Comment: If it's null I wouldn't want it to be included however. so AND doesn't quite work.

Comment: 1 min let me look through my code and the answer to the null is do an if else statement

Comment: Problem is, it's going to be a lot of if statements and on top of that if one is null but the other isn't etc

Comment: sorry can't help you but i did do qucik reserch and skimmed through some text google  union query